# Character ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hopefully this'll just be a quicky.

I'm using the toCharArray(); function to create an ArrayList, I need to use characters in my Arraylist as I will have zero values at the start of my number and I'm pretty sure using int's will delete these. Everything is going well I just can't figure out how to select the items in the list. I have read about the .get() function but I can only get this to work when I do an ArrayList of ints.

It's perfectly possible that the .get() function is fine but I haven't actually implemented the ArrayList properly here's my code...

```
package com.activecactus.spanish_bingo1_2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Number_Reader extends Activity {

EditText readNumberET;
TextView numberLengthTV;
int currentLength;
List<String> digits = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_number__reader);

    readNumberET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.read_input);
    numberLengthTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_length);
}

public void btn_zero_click(View view) {
    add("0");}
public void btn_one_click(View view) {
    add("1");}
public void btn_two_click(View view) {
    add("2");}
public void btn_three_click(View view) {
    add("3");}
public void btn_four_click(View view) {
    add("4");}
public void btn_five_click(View view) {
    add("5");}
public void btn_six_click(View view) {
    add("6");}
public void btn_seven_click(View view) {
    add("7");}
public void btn_eight_click(View view) {
    add("8");}
public void btn_nine_click(View view) {
    add("9");}

public void add(String num)
{
    currentLength++;
    readNumberET.append(num);
}

public void onSendRead(View view) {

    int n = Integer.parseInt(readNumberET.getText().toString());

    String newNumber = String.format("%04d", n);

    char[] digits = newNumber.toCharArray();

    String str = (String) digits.get(0);

    numberLengthTV.setText(str);

}


public void onSendClear(View view) {
    readNumberET.setText(null);
    digits.clear();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i'm not getting it... if you use an array, then just say "String str = (String) digits[0];" or, if you're using an List, maybe you create the list as "ArrayList<Character> digits = new ArrayList(newNumber.toCharArray() );" which makes digits.get(0) working...

Comment: According to your question, you simply want to get a character from string using the index don't you?

Comment: Your problem statement is entirely unclear. Istead of getting right to discussing your solution, you should clearly present your problem, and a great way to do that is to provide a sample input and expected output/result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what it is that your trying to achieve and why you specifically need to use an `ArrayList`, but I can describe the problem you are facing with your code and how you might fix it. At the moment you declare your `ArrayList` variable `digits` here;

```
List<String> digits = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And in your OnSendRead() method you are creating a second `digits` variable that **hides** your `ArrayList` variable of the same name. Ie, here;

```
char[] digits = newNumber.toCharArray();
String str = (String) digits.get(0);
```

I would suggest simply dropping the `ArrayList` and using the correct syntax with the new basic array you create in this method like so;

```
char[] digits = newNumber.toCharArray();
String str = digits[0]+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onSendRead(View view) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(readNumberET.getText().toString());
    String newNumber = String.format("%04d", n);
    numberLengthTV.setText(newNumber);
}
```

The `toCharArray()` is not needed, as you have already padded the number with zeroes.

```
public void add(String num) {
    if (currentLength < 4) {
        currentLength++;
        readNumberET.append(num);
    }
}
```

You might use:

```
String s = "0123";
s = s.substring(1); // "123"
s += '4'; // "1234"
```